# Compare multiple items in a list at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to select multiple items from a list and see if they are all the same or not. Something like this:

```
    if list1[:3] == 'x':
        Do Something....
```

So I need to know if items 0-3 in the list equal the character 'x'. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can't think of *any* way to accomplish this?!?

Comment: What if there are less than 3 elements in your list?

Comment: Although it may seem obvious to you Scott Hunter it was not obvious to me at the time as i am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most readable/efficient way seems to be:

```
 if all(v == 'x' for v in list[:3]):
    # do something
```

Comment: You should [accept the answer](http://i.imgur.com/XgH04Em.png) if it answer your needs.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it at once may be:

```
if list[:3] == 3*['x']:
    # DO something
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
subArr = list1[:3]
if len([i for i in subArr if i == 'x']) == len(subArr):
  #OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
if {x} == set(list1[:3]):
    #do something
```

Comment: if you had less than 3 elements in the list this could incorrectly return True, you need to make sure the length of list1[:3] is 3